# Dropbox indicates a file is uploading, though all files and folders have green checks

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

How can I reset the Dropbox app to stop saying it's uploading when all the files in my folder are showing up everywhere else, and none of the other instances show uploads?

the message I see is:

> Dropbox 1.4.7
>   Uploading 1 file...

But there is no indication as to what the file is.

Comment: the accepted [answer](http://superuser.com/a/474226/978) to another [issue](http://superuser.com/q/474217/978) I had did not help (clearing the cache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with files having invalid characters (specifically, a colon) - https://www.dropbox.com/bad_files_check can help you find if you have any invalid file names.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hidden file being uploaded.
Sometimes this happens when a file is being edited.

Restarting should do the trick.

Comment: I was hoping that too - have had several power cycles :(

Comment: I'd open up Process Monitor and filter to DropBox to see what it's up to.