# Dropbox says it cannot sync a file due to space constraints

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

I ran past my storage allocation with Dropbox yesterday.

After cleaning-up my folder, I have plenty of space again.

However, Dropbox shows that it cannot sync a file because there is no space, yet when I check the website or other machines linked, I see the file there - with a green check.

Is there a way to clear this message?

> Can't sync "7linux_tuning.mp3": out of space in your Dropbox

But I am only using:

> 93.6% of 6.2 GB used

The file in question is only 30MB, and should fit fine (and, in fact, does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may sound like a stupid question, but do you have enough space on your physical drive? Since Dropbox acts as a folder on your physical drive there has to be enough space on that drive as well for it to sync. It sounds like you're saying the file does fit on your physical drive by your saying "The file in question is only 30MB, and should fit fine (and, in fact, does)." but I wanted to just throw this first easy solution out there for you.

**Edit:**

Have you cleared the Dropbox cache? This is the path in Windows Explorer (assuming you're using Windows 7) `%HOMEPATH%\Dropbox\.dropbox.cache` type that line in the location bar in Windows Explorer and it should take you to the dropbox cache folder. The cache folder is deleted automatically every 3 days, but if you just recently deleted a lot of files this could be taking up valuable space in your dropbox folder.

Comment: I have 100G free on the local drive

Comment: Okay. That's good. Have you cleared the Dropbox cache? This is the path in Windows Explorer (assuming you're using Windows 7) %HOMEPATH%\Dropbox\.dropbox.cache type that line in the location bar in Windows Explorer and it should take you to the dropbox cache folder. The cache folder is deleted automatically every 3 days, but if you just recently deleted a lot of files this could be taking up valuable space in your dropbox folder.

Comment: did not know about the `%HOMEPATH%\Dropbox\.dropbox.cache` trick - that solved this problem :) .. I had a dir from June hanging out plus three more from this week

Comment: I periodically delete everything in my `...\Dropbox\.dropbox.cache` by adding it as a custom folder to be cleaned in my [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) settings. Also not that you can move your Dropbox folder anywhere -- like out of the default Windows subdirectory it's put in by default.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad I could help.